# How to put this dash pseudo element between li's

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I would like this red dash to be equally positioned between 1st and 2nd(and 2nd and 3rd) "li" in this list, but it appears above it and not on the left side. Is it possible to do it this way? Here's the example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENzXao

This is what I am trying to accomplish: http://sketchtoy.com/67757539

```
.main__headers--info ul li {
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main__headers--info ul li:nth-child(2),
.main__headers--info ul li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.main__headers--info ul li:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
}

<div class="main__headers--info">
  <ul>
    <li>lorem lorem</li>
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>something</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want the red dash to be on both 1st and 2nd??

Comment: Red dash should appear before the second "li" and before the third "li", but not before the first one

Comment: Then just modify `.main__headers--info ul li:nth-child(2)::before {` to `.main__headers--info ul li:nth-child(2)::before,.main__headers--info ul li:nth-child(3)::before {`?

Comment: or do `.main__headers--info ul li:not(:first-of-type)::before {`

Comment: This is what I am trying to accomplish: http://sketchtoy.com/67757539

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would remove the margins and just add inline-block pseudo-elements:

```css
.main__headers--info > ul > li {
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.main__headers--info > ul > li:not(:first-child)::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main__headers--info">
  <ul>
    <li>lorem lorem</li>
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>something</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

See [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/1529630) if the space before the pseudo-elements annoys you.

Comment: Thank you, I have added margins here =>.main__headers--info ul li:not(:first-child)::before { margin: 0px 20px; } , works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

**I have modified the pen.**

here is the demo If i got your question correctly.

add this css code to the 2nd and 3rd li's :before element

```
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
```

and `position: relative` to li element
    [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENzXao?editors=1100)

Comment: this is what I am trying to accomplish, edited question: http://sketchtoy.com/67757539

Comment: @Smithy I have modified the pen.

Answer (score 0):

Here, working example, will put the red line on any li-element not the first.

```css
.main__headers--info ul li {
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main__headers--info ul li:nth-child(2),
.main__headers--info ul li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.main__headers--info ul li:not(:first-of-type)::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main__headers--info">
  <ul>
    <li>lorem lorem</li>
    <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>something</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you check this sketch example, red dash should be between and not above the li's  http://sketchtoy.com/67757539

Comment: Then you cannot use borders.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  width: 100%; }

.seperator {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0 1px;
  margin-top: 0 !important; }
  .seperator hr {
    height: 2px;
    background: gray;
    border: none;
    vertical-align: middle; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="">
       Text
    </div>

    <div class="seperator"><hr></div>

    <div class="">
        Text
    </div>

    <div class="seperator"><hr></div>

    <div class="">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
```